# QGis Polygon rotate/move parallel to a line

Tags: qgis, polygon

I would like to know if there is any way for a polygon to be rotated and/or moved so that one of its sides is parallel to a line or to the side of another polygon.

I found that before there was a plugin that did it.

[Plugin Polygons Parallel to Line](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/PolygonsParallelToLine/)

Position Initial:

[image]

Rotate to be Parallel:

[image]

Rotate anb move to be Parallel:

[image]